# pass bool to qdialog

Tags: c++, qt, setter, qdialog

I'm trying to pass a bool to a qdialog via a setter method; the code compiles, but the value doesn't seem to take in the dialog. I've included just the pertinent code, I hope it's readable. What am I missing here?

//  forcequitDialog h file

```
public:
setAction(const bool &takeaction);

private:
     bool m_action;
```

// forcequitDialog.cpp

```
  forcequitDialog::forcequitDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::forcequitDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);  

       if (m_action)
          ui->title->setText("Start Application");
        else
       ui->title->setText("Stop Application");

forcequitDialog::~forcequitDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}



  void forcequitDialog::setAction(const bool &takeaction)
    {
        m_action = takeaction;



    }
```

// MainWindow.cpp

```
 forcequitDialog dialog;

    dialog.setAction(true);  // pass value to dialog

    dialog.exec();
```

Comment: Where is the code commented "doesn't work"? Surely not in the global scope?

Comment: @krzaq I've added code.

Comment: The code still looks a little wonky as pasted, but you appear to be using `m_action` in the constructor then calling `setAction(true)` afterwards.

Comment: @ken-y-n my mainwindow.cpp passes the value via dialog.setAction(true); then calls dialog.exec()  I don't understand what's wonky.

Comment: @Alan the value passed in `setAction` is being passed long after the title has been set.

Comment: @Alan, please do not edit the question to correct the issue we have pointed out, as it will confuse later readers and makes the comments and answer redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
forcequitDialog dialog; // constructor called here
```

Your lines:

```
if (m_action)  // doesn't work
    ui->title->setText("Start Application");
else
    ui->title->setText("Stop Application");
```

are executed before your call to:

```
dialog.setAction(true);  // pass value to dialog
```

Either move these instructions into setAction() function or pass `takeaction` to your constructor.

btw: using a const reference for a bool is useless, it's not a heavy object.